# Forward to a specific page after logging in

Tags: angularjs, url, redirect, authentication

I have an Angular app in which a user is redirected to the login page if they try to access a page for which they need to be authenticated.  Currently, when the user is successfully authenticated from the login page, they are redirected to a default start page.  The change that I need to make is this:

When a user is attempting to browse to a specific page and needs to login, after the user has successfully logged in, the site should forward the user to the page they wanted.

Any ideas on how this can be done in AngularJS?

Comment: You should be able to do that with a routing config function and/or the login controller. Unfortunately, your question is too broad.

Comment: I don't understand why this is voted down.  I am looking for guidance here.  I do have a login controller that is associated with the login page.  When the form on that page is submitted, the controller checks that the credentials are appropriate and uses `$location.url('/defaultPath');` to navigate to the default path.  Instead of navigating to the default path, I want the user redirected to the page that they want.

Comment: @DelvinDefoe facing the same issue here.if your problem resoled can you tell me how to do that?Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 2):

OK, after some research I was able to come up with the solution below:

In `app.js` I added the following `run` method.

```
angular.module('MainModule', [])
...
.run(function($rootScope, $location, UserService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        if ((!UserService.isUserLoggedIn()) && ($location.path() !== '/login')) {
            $rootScope.postLoginRoute = $location.path();
            $location.path('/login').replace();
        }
    });
});
```

In my loginController I was able to redirect the user to the page they desire as follows:

```
function loginController($scope, $location, UserService, $rootScope){  
    $scope.submit = function() {
        if(UserService.validateCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password)){
            if($rootScope.postLoginRoute){
                $location.url($rootScope.postLoginRoute);
            } else{
                $location.path('/defaultPage');
            }
            $rootScope.postLoginRoute = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Another solution is available at [this location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161764/angularjs-redirection-after-login), but it involves using cookies.